# Multiple Branch Building in Jenkins with SVN

Tags: build, jenkins, build-process

I have to set up a project which has multiple active branches in Jenkins .The source repository is SVN .What is the best  Stratergy for building different branches in Jenkins with SVN ,should i create a job for every branch or is there some way to build every branch in one job.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, creating a job for every branch seems to be the way people do it for now, see e.g. http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/continuous-integration-and-feature-branches/#!/ and the links under material used.

It seems a common thing to do is to have some sort of script create the jobs for you either using the api or modifiyng directly in the config.xml's on the filesystem.